# How to sort alphanumeric and special character values of column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to sort a column which has numeric, alphanumeric and special character data.

My data:

```
567865
798172
hjy733
y@y899
$#798e
jk90&32
```

into the output:

```
567865
798172
$#798e
y@y899
jk90&32
```

Comment: (1) Why the simple `order by` won't work for you? (2) Why the sorted output has fewer values than unsorted?

Comment: So what sort order is that? Not alphanumeric for sure and not ASCII either. If you want us to help you need to explain your requirements.

Comment: Just for the humor of it`ORDER BY CASE WHEN col = '567865' then 1
              WHEN col = '798172' then 2
              when col = '$#798e' then 3
              when col = 'y@y899' then 4
              when col = 'jk90&32' then 5
              else 9999 end`  since I can't figure out based on the example data what pattern this follows.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a fun way to do it, if this is what you are trying to do. :-)

```
SELECT S.COL1,
RESULT.REGEXP 

FROM YOURDATA S

LEFT JOIN (  SELECT COL1, 
                CASE 
                WHEN regexp_like (substr (COL1, 1, 1), '([[:digit:]]$)')  THEN 'A' -- numeric
                WHEN regexp_like (substr (COL1, 1, 1), '[^a-zA-Z0-9]')    THEN 'B' -- symbol
                WHEN regexp_like (substr (COL1, 1, 1), '([[:alpha:]]$)')  THEN 'C' -- alpha           
                ELSE 'X'
                END AS REGEXP
            FROM YOURDATA
            )RESULT ON S.COL1 = RESULT.COL1
ORDER BY RESULT.REGEXP, S.COL1
```